# find first number in each line, do some arithmetic and replace it

Tags: bash, awk, sed

I have hundreds of lines like this one:
`INSERT INTO table1 VALUES (5566, 1979, 'Montag', '06:00', '19:00', 1, 'ON', NULL`

 I need to add to the first number `5566` another number, let say `50` and this in each line. 
There is many ways how to get the first number with sed or awk but how can I perform the arithmetic and replace the number? 
Any hints?

Comment: 5566 is not actually the first number on that line. (The first number is 1, as in `table1`.) Can you provide a more precise description of the number you need to change, with other possible lines?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do use this awk:

```
s='INSERT INTO table1 VALUES (5566, 1979, 'Montag', '06:00', '19:00', 1, 'ON', NULL'
echo "$s"|awk '{sub(/[^0-9]+/, "", $5); $5+=50; $5="(" $5 ","} 1'
INSERT INTO table1 VALUES (5616, 1979, Montag, 06:00, 19:00, 1, ON, NULL
```